# Express SDP problem in CSDP

Tags: semidefinite-programming

I am trying to use CSDP and am struggling with this.

Consider for example the SDP problem proposed by prof. Borchers [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/24821/479). Namely:

$$\max_{A,z} \sum_{i} z_{i}\quad\text{subject to}\quad\mbox{tr}(P_{i}A) \geq z_{i},\quad i=1, 2, \ldots, n.\quad A \succeq 0.$$

I am wondering how one represents it in the [standard CSDP format](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcsdp/Rcsdp.pdf):

$$\max_{X} \mbox{Tr}(CX)\quad\text{subject to}\quad\mbox{tr}(A_{i}X)= b_{i},\quad i=1, 2, \ldots, n.\quad X \succeq 0.$$

More precisely, I can see how to specify the $A_i$'s. My problem is how to express the $\sum_i z_i$ in the objective function as $\mbox{Tr}(CX)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inequality constraints in an SDP can be turned into equality constraints by introducing non-negative slack variables.  If your original problem is

$\max \Sigma_{i=1}^{n} z_{i}$

subject to

$\mbox{tr}(P_{i}X) \geq z_{i}\;\;$  $i=1, 2, \ldots, n$

$ X \succeq 0$

You can rewrite the constraints as

$\mbox{tr}(P_{i}X) - z_{i} \geq 0\;\;$  $i=1, 2, \ldots, n.$

You can then introduce slack variables $w_{i}$, $i=1, 2, \ldots, n$ and 
write the constraints as

$\mbox{tr}(P_{i}X) - z_{i} -w_{i} = 0\;\;$  $i=1, 2, \ldots, n.$

where $w_{i} \geq 0$, $i=1, 2, \ldots, n$.

I'll assume for this answer that the $z_{i}$ variables are also nonnegative.  If they're free to be negative, you could handle this by 
writing $z_{i}=r_{i}-s_{i}$, where $r, s \geq 0$.

Let $Z=\mbox{diag}(z)$ and $W=\mbox{diag}(w)$.  Let

$V=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
X  &  0  & 0 \\
0  &  Z  & 0 \\
0  &  0  & W \\
\end{array}
\right]$.

Let

$C=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
0  &  0  & 0 \\
0  &  I  & 0 \\
0  &  0  & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]$.

Note that $\mbox{tr}(CV)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} z_{i}$.

Let

$A_{i}=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
P_{i} &  0  & 0 \\
0  &  -E_{i,i}  & 0 \\
0  &  0  & -E_{i,i} \\
\end{array}
\right]\;\;$ $i=1, 2, \ldots, n$.

Here $E_{i,i}$ is the 0 matrix with a single $1$ in the $(i,i)$ position.

Now the original problem can be written in standard form as

$\max \mbox{tr}(CV)$

subject to

$\mbox{tr}(A_{i}V)=b_{i}\;\;$ $i=1, 2, \ldots, n$

$V \succeq 0$.

Note that $V$ is a block diagonal matrix, and that furthermore, $Z$ and $W$ are diagonal blocks.  In the SDPA sparse matrix format it is easy to 
encode $X$ as an $n$ by $n$ positive semidefinite block and $Z$ and $W$ as $n$ by $1$ vectors of non-negative variables.  The additional storage required for $Z$ and $W$ is minimal.

The constraint $V \succeq 0$ ensures that all of the blocks on the diagonal of $V$ are positive semidefinite.  In particular, $X \succeq 0$, 
$z \geq 0$, and $w \geq 0$.

I assume that you probably have additional linear constraints on $X$ and $z$.  These can easily be added to the formulation.

Comment: Thanks. One more question: does using $-\pmb I$ as the central entry of $\pmb C$ compromises the concavity of the problem?

Comment: No.  The objective $\mbox{tr}(CV)$ is always linear and thus both convex and concave.

Comment: In case you weren't aware, $\mbox{tr}(CV)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} C_{i,j}V_{i,j}$  This is a linear combination of the elements of $V$.